# JavaFX VBox children duplicates

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

So I have a HashMap that has a size of let's say 5. So what I am trying to do is to add as many panes as the same size of the HashMap.

I already have a Pane (aNewPane) defined in my .FXML file, that's nested in a VBox called "articleInfoBox".

So when I am trying to make more panes based on the size of my HashMap im getting this error:

```
/C:/Users/Moeme/Documents/School/HsLeiden/2de%20jaars/IPSEN2/IPSEN2-FE/target/classes/fxml/article.fxml

    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2516)
    at Controller.NavigationSceneController.openArticlePage(NavigationSceneController.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.1/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox[id=articleInfoPane]
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.1/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:561)
    at javafx.base@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:205)
    at Controller.ArticleController.getArticles(ArticleController.java:92)
    at Controller.ArticleController.initialize(ArticleController.java:47)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2655)
    ... 57 more
```

This is how I initialise the FXML attritbutes:

```
@FXML private VBox articleInfoPane = new VBox();
@FXML private Pane aNewPane;
```

The code that's trying to make a new pane is:

```
for (int a = 0; a < AllArticleItems.size(); a++){
            Text text = new Text();
            text.setText("some text");
            aNewPane.getChildren().add(text);
            articleInfoBox.getChildren().add(aNewPane);
        }
```

The FXML:

```
<VBox fx:id="articleInfoPane" layoutX="65.0" layoutY="183.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="990.0">
         <children>
            <Pane fx:id="aNewPane" prefHeight="74.0" prefWidth="975.0" style="-fx-background-color: white; -fx-background-radius: 8;">

            </Pane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
```

Comment: You need to actually create a new pane on every iteration of the loop, instead of repeatedly adding the same pane to `articleInfoPane`. Just create the pane in code, in the loop, instead of in FXML.

Comment: Off-topic, but consider using a `Label` (which can be styled) instead of a `Text` inside a `Pane`.